# Handle permission denied in bash script

Tags: bash, scripting, permissions

I want to try some script.

1. check read & write permission to file /opt/test/some.log
2. if getting permission denied error, create file in /tmp/, else write somethign to /opt/test/some.log

Thanks,
bala.

tail /opt/test/some.log | grep denied

Not sure how to process this into if.

Comment: Please post your script in your question (ideally as a code block). What exactly is the question? The expected structure is: _I have this script, when I run it it does A, but I was expecting B._ I can’t see any of this. Use e.g. `[[ -w /opt/test/some.log ]]` to check if you can write a file.

Comment: Thanks @AndrejPodzimek,

From your comment, i got what I wanted.

I was looking for this -w option. Now it works for me.

if ! [ -w /opt/test/some.log ]; then
 echo "Do not have permission to write"
 echo "test" >> /tmp/some.log
fi

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @AndrejPodzimek,

Now, it works for me.

```
if ! [ -w /opt/test/some.log ]; then
 echo "Do not have permission to write"
 echo "test" >> /tmp/some.log
fi
```

Comment: Learn to use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu. Mouse select text you want to format as `code/data/output/exactTxtErrMsgs` then click the `{}` "icon" in the Edit menu above the text entry box to get correct formatting. Glad you solved your probleml Good luck.